# What is the problem of my plant

Tags: plant-health

[image: dry leaves]

I have this plant that I bought one month ago. Its leaves start to dry. I don't put much water, just when I feel the soil starts to dry. The plant is in the living room with no direct sunlight but enough light.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a some problem happening in the soil.  Normally I would say that is being over-watered.  The saucer on the pot.  Is that just decorative.  In other words does the pot actually have holes in the bottom if not, then you need to put your plant in a pot with holes.

There are many advantages to have holes in the bottom of the pot.  The first is to make sure any excess water is not sitting in the bottom of the pot rotting the roots.
The other is to flush out the salts, chloramine or chlorine out of the soil during each watering.  The build up of the chemicals are toxic to plants.

Even if you have holes in the bottom you have could have build up of chemicals in your soil.  You should switch to distilled, reverse osmosis or rain water.  A reverse osmosis filter systems have become affordable.   Of course this depends on where in the world you live.   Many plants benefit from these salt free water.   If you have access to rain water you can start collecting it to water your plants, but that is not always available.   You can purchase RO or distilled water.  Distilled water is normally the more pricey of the two.  A regular filter is better than nothing, but they do not clean the water as much as OR or distilled.

If you do have holes in the bottom of your pot, you should flush it out.  You wanted to pour the amount of water, equal to what the pot with out soil would hold.   You put all this water through the soil.    Then repeat in a couple hours.  This will flush out your pot of chemical build-up.  Even if all you have is your normal tap water it will at least flush out some of the build up.

If your pot does not have holes in the bottom, you can buy a plastic pot with holes that slips into your current pot without holes.  After each watering, dump out the excess water in the ceramic pot without holes.

Good Luck.